# How to check Mobile screen in Invision Studio app on mobile

Tags: interface-design, invision-studio

I have created a Mobile Login Screen on Invision Studio On my Mac now I want to check the screen on mobile if the font size is correct or no if the spacing is right.

Kindly help me to check my Invision work on mobile

Answer (score 1):

You can simply download invision mobile app on iOS and mirror your design on the phone. All you have to do is :

1.download the app on iOS

2.open invision on your Mac ( imac or macbook)

3.click on "in" icon beside play button on the invision software on your mac (top right corner). It will show you a QR-Code

4.Open invision app on your iOS device and switch to scan QR-Code tab.

5.put your phone camera on the qr-Code shown on your screen and you are good to go.

invision ios app download link:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/invision-design-prototype/id990700027?mt=8

Bests,